# Filter pandas dataframe date column X months from start of the month

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Having trouble finding a solution for my problem.

Supose I have a df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':np.random.randn(len(date_rng)),'created_at':pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2020-12-31', freq='D')})
df
```

output is:

```
       col      created_at
0   1.764052    2020-01-01
1   0.400157    2020-01-02
2   0.978738    2020-01-03
3   2.240893    2020-01-04
4   1.867558    2020-01-05
... ... ...
361 0.003771    2020-12-27
362 0.931848    2020-12-28
363 0.339965    2020-12-29
364 -0.015682   2020-12-30
365 0.160928    2020-12-31
```

so problem is that I want to filter the dataframe to show the last 6 months to the first of the month. For example if today (October 23 2020), I want the dataframe to bring results from April 1st.

when in November, first date result should be May 1st regardless of the November date.

Any ideas of how to do it?

This is supposed to run automatically, so something like:

```
df = df[(df.created_at.dt.month >= datetime.datetime.utcnow().month)
                    & (df.created_at.dt.year==datetime.datetime.utcnow().year)]
```

wont work.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use between to sepcify a condition between two values:

```
today = datetime.today()
target = today - timedelta(days=180)
df = df[lambda x: x['created_at'].between(datetime(target.year,target.month,1),today)]
```